# What does this mean? #if !(arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))

Tags: swift, if-statement, architecture

I came across this unusual code in a tutorial I was using.

```
#if !(arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))
func sqrt(a: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
return CGFloat(sqrtf(Float(a)))
}
#endif
```

It looks nothing like the code I've been learning so far. I know it's a square root function but the hashtag? Something about my computer architecture?

Please explain it to me in simple terms.

Comment: Just search for "#if" in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book...

Comment: Btw, that code is not needed anymore. Current Swift has `sqrt()` implemented for Float, Double and CGFloat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#if condition
// Code in here
#endif
```

This is a **conditional compilation directive** - it is used to hide blocks of code from the compiler. The code in the block is only compiled if the condition is true.

It's supported in many languages, notably C and C++. It is often used to account for processor architecture and operating system differences - allowing one code-base to compile on many different platforms.

It can also be used to remove debugging/tracing code in a release build.

The condition is evaluated once at *compile time*, normally in an initial pass over the source code before the main compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can set those kind of *conditional compilation directive* for various purpose.

For example you might have an environnement for DEBUG and one for RELEASE, depending on which you wan't to compile your might not use the same functions / values.

In you case, `#if !(arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))` is to determine the architecture of your device (or simulator).

Indeed, some iDevice run 32bits and others 64bits (5S and newer). Float aren't represented the same way.

As @Martin wrote, you might not have to use this code anymore :)

Comment: The #if checks for 64-bit vs 32-bit runtime, *not* for simulator vs device. There are 64-bit devices (iPhone 5s and newer) which can run both 32-bit and 64-bit code.